# Why is a horseshoe not a ring

Tags: general-topology

Topologically speaking, the shape of a horseshoe is **not** the same structure as a (physical) ring, because loops on a horseshoe are always contractible.

But we can take the ends of a horseshoe, and practically fuse them together, say with an arc-welder.

> Does this make a horseshoe equivalent to a ring in any sense?

Mathematically, what is the topological effect of removing/adding the positive $x$-axis from the annulus $0<x^2+y^2\le1$?

Comment: If you're going to allow cutting or welding, I can hardly think of anything that isn't something else.

Comment: if its a donut, can you eat it?

Comment: Not all loops on a horseshoe are contractible; there are always holes for the nails to go through.

Answer (score 2):

Welding, in topology, is done via *continuous surjections*. You've essentially observed that there is a continuous surjection from $[0, 1]$ to $S^1$. It's not hard to see that there's also a continuous surjection from $S^1$ back to $[0, 1]$: hammer your circle flat.

We could study topological spaces modulo "bi-quotientability", but this would lose a lot of structure. For instance, all positive-dimensional manifolds would be equivalent to each other, and that's just for starters. So from the perspective of algebraic topology of "nice" spaces, this notion seems bad. It's possible it behaves interestingly in the context of other, very weird (from a geometrical perspective) spaces, but I don't know about that.